# AWS Mysql 5.5.40 security group issues Forced update

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

We are running MYSQL 5.5.40 and Amazon forced an upgrade on us a few days ago. Our App servers can no longer connect to the database server. It appears that there is an issue with our security groups.

We do have an instance that is running and connecting but it was spawned a few weeks ago. The new app servers cannot connect.
Any help much appreciated as our site cannot really function on a single app server.

Comment: And the "issue with our security groups" is...?

Comment: We are assuming the security groups are now not allowing the app server to connect to the database

Comment: Have you checked them?

Comment: How are you referencing the RDS instance?  When it was upgraded its IP address likely changed, so if you're using a hardcoded IP address or a custom DNS record that's not pointing to the RDS endpoint then you're likely not connecting to the right address.

Answer (score 0):

If you have double-checked everything and you're certain there's no mistake in your security group set up, you can try modifying and re-saving your security groups. I once had to do that for them to be picked up after making unrelated changes, though it's much more likely to be a mistake in setup.